# change multiple images in buttons

Tags: javascript, html

Hello stackoverflow community,

right now I am starting to learn javascript. I have a problem with the following code. I wan't to display two buttons. If I press one of the buttons, the image in the button should change. I want to do this with one function. Is that possible? When I send the output from the function to the console it says the src is null. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function pickDice(dice) {
  var image = document.getElementById('dice');

  console.log(image.src)

  if (image.src.match("d4_grey.png")) {
    image.src = "d4_green.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("d4_green.png")) {
    image.src = "d4_grey.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("d6_grey.png")) {
    image.src = "d6_red.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("d6_red.png")) {
    image.src = "d6_grey.png";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>P&P System</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button onclick="pickDice('d4_image')"><img id="d4_image" src="d4_grey.png" style="width:64px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="pickDice('d6_image')"><img id="d6_image" src="d6_grey.png" style="width:64px"></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `var image = document.getElementById('dice');` You don't have an element with `id="dice"` in your HTML. It looks like you just want to reference the argument that was passed in `dice.src`

Comment: Ok that seems logic. But how can i refrence both buttons/the images with one function? Is that possible?

Comment: add a common class to each button and use `var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("your_common_class_name")` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Other option is use "this" inside your function, then you can access to this.parentElment or this.parentElement.children[0], I have not tried this code but I think It can work :)

Comment: You can just simply use <td><button onclick="pickDice('d4_green.png')"><img id="d4_image" src="d4_grey.png" style="width:64px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="pickDice('d6_red.png')"><img id="d6_image" src="d6_grey.png" style="width:64px"></button></td> , function pickDice(imagesrc) {
  var image = document.getElementById('dice');
  image.src = imagesrc;
  alert(image.src)
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you've passed an argument to the function, which makes the `dice` variable available to that function, but because you wrapped that variable-name in quotes you're using the literal string `'dice'` instead of the string that you passed in; so instead of:

```
var image = document.getElementById('dice');
```

you should, instead, use:

```
var image = document.getElementById(dice);
```

```js
function pickDice(dice) {
  var image = document.getElementById(dice);

  console.log(image.src)

  if (image.src.match("d4_grey.png")) {
    image.src = "d4_green.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("d4_green.png")) {
    image.src = "d4_grey.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("d6_grey.png")) {
    image.src = "d6_red.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("d6_red.png")) {
    image.src = "d6_grey.png";
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- note that I'm using HTML encoded ampersand instead of 'just' the
     & character: -->
<h1>P&amp;P System</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button onclick="pickDice('d4_image')"><img id="d4_image" src="d4_grey.png" style="width:64px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="pickDice('d6_image')"><img id="d6_image" src="d6_grey.png" style="width:64px"></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This will work, in that if you view the console logs you'll see that the `src` property of the relevant `<img>` element is updated.

However, you're clearly repeating code in your function; what was two lines for one `<button>` becomes four lines for two, will become six lines for three...

Because the HTML structure – in your posted example – is consistent you may as well use that and navigate the DOM within the function. If you do this then you can use the following approach:

```js
// here we pass in a reference to the <button> element
// that was clicked (the variable name can be anything):
function pickDice(button) {

  // retrieving the first, if any, <img> element within
  // the <button>, using Element.querySelector():
  var image = button.querySelector('img');

  console.log(image.src)

  if (image.src.match("d4_grey.png")) {
    image.src = "d4_green.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("d4_green.png")) {
    image.src = "d4_grey.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("d6_grey.png")) {
    image.src = "d6_red.png";
  } else if (image.src.match("d6_red.png")) {
    image.src = "d6_grey.png";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>P&amp;P System</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- note that we pass in the keyword 'this', a reference to
           the current Node, the <button> element: -->
      <button onclick="pickDice(this)"><img id="d4_image" src="d4_grey.png" style="width:64px;"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="pickDice(this)"><img id="d6_image" src="d6_grey.png" style="width:64px"></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This, again, will work, demonstrated by viewing the console logs and simplifies the code, and maintenance, a little as you no longer have to write in the `id` of the relevant `<img>`, although this approach *does* require the structure to remain consistent.

However, while we've simplified one aspect of the code there is still repetition; so now we can take advantage of custom `data-*` attributes to hold information accessible to the function:

```js
function pickDice(button) {
  var image = button.querySelector('img'),
    // we define the default colour of the image:
    defaultColour = 'grey',
    // we retrieve the defined alternate colour,
    // held in the `data-alt` attribute-value using
    // the Element.dataset API:
    altColour = image.dataset.alt;

  console.log(image.src);

  // if the string held in the image.src property-value
  // includes the value held in the altColour variable:
  if (image.src.includes(altColour)) {
    // we use String.prototype.replace() to replace that
    // String with the defaultColour:
    image.src = image.src.replace(altColour, defaultColour);
  } else {
    // otherwise we replace the defaultColour String with
    // the altColour:
    image.src = image.src.replace(defaultColour, altColour);
  }

}
```

```html
<h1>P&amp;P System</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="pickDice(this)">
        <!-- here we pass in the alternative colour for the
             current element using the data-alt attribute-value: -->
        <img id="d4_image" src="d4_grey.png" data-alt="green" style="width:64px;">
      </button></td>
    <td>
      <button onclick="pickDice(this)">
        <img id="d6_image" src="d6_grey.png" data-alt="red" style="width:64px">
      </button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The above can be shortened a little using a ternary expression:

```js
function pickDice(button) {
  var image = button.querySelector('img'),
    defaultColour = 'grey',
    altColour = image.dataset.alt;

  console.log(image.src);

  // a conditional (ternary) operator works via an assessment,
  // followed by the response in the event the assessment is true/truthy
  // followed by the response for the assessment being false/falsey:
  // assessment ? return_if_true : return_if_false;
  // so here we determine if the property-value of the image's src
  // includes the altColour String, if so we return the image.src property
  // after replacing altColour with defaultColour, otherwise we return the
  // image.src after replacing defaultColour with altColour:
  image.src = image.src.includes(altColour) ? image.src.replace(altColour, defaultColour) : image.src.replace(defaultColour, altColour);

}
```

```html
<h1>P&amp;P System</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="pickDice(this)">
        <img id="d4_image" src="d4_grey.png" data-alt="green" style="width:64px;">
      </button></td>
    <td>
      <button onclick="pickDice(this)">
        <img id="d6_image" src="d6_grey.png" data-alt="red" style="width:64px">
      </button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Of course this still involves a repetitive calls to `String.prototype.replace()`, which can be simplified a little using the following, though it does create extra variables:

```js
function pickDice(button) {
  var image = button.querySelector('img'),
    defaultColour = 'grey',
    altColour = image.dataset.alt,
    // finding whether the image.src property-value includes
    // the altColour:
    boolSwitch = image.src.includes(altColour),
    // if the switch is true (and the image.src includes the altColour)
    // we set altColour as the currentColour, otherwise we use
    // the defaultColour:
    currentColour = boolSwitch ? altColour : defaultColour,
    // because we want to switch from the default to the alt we use the
    // same ternary assessment, but reverse the order of the defaultColour
    // and altColour; so that the newColour is not the same as the
    // currentColour:
    newColour = boolSwitch ? defaultColour : altColour;

  console.log(image.src);

  // here we simply update the image.src replacing the currentColour with
  // the newColour:
  image.src = image.src.replace(currentColour, newColour);

}
```

```html
<h1>P&amp;P System</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="pickDice(this)">
        <img id="d4_image" src="d4_grey.png" data-alt="green" style="width:64px;">
      </button></td>
    <td>
      <button onclick="pickDice(this)">
        <img id="d6_image" src="d6_grey.png" data-alt="red" style="width:64px">
      </button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It's also worth noting that the event-handler for the `click` event can be moved out of the HTML – using `EventTarget.addEventListener()` – for a less obtrusive JavaScript, which again makes maintenance a little easier:

```js
// note the removal of the 'button' argument:
function pickDice() {
  // using EventTarget.addEventListener() automagically
  // passes the element, in this case the <button>, in
  // as the 'this' node; so here instead of
  // button.querySelector('img') we can instead use:
  var image = this.querySelector('img'),
    defaultColour = 'grey',
    altColour = image.dataset.alt,
    boolSwitch = image.src.includes(altColour),
    currentColour = boolSwitch ? altColour : defaultColour,
    newColour = boolSwitch ? defaultColour : altColour;

  console.log(image.src);

  image.src = image.src.replace(currentColour, newColour);

}

// here we retrieve all <button> elements from within all <table>
// elements, and iterate over the collection using
// NodeList.forEach():
document.querySelectorAll('table button').forEach(
  // here we use Arrow function syntax to pass in the
  // current element ('el') to the function body;
  // binding the pickDice() function (note the deliberate
  // lack of parentheses after the function name) as the
  // event-handler for the 'click' event:
  (el) => el.addEventListener('click', pickDice)
);
```

```html
<h1>P&amp;P System</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button>
        <img id="d4_image" src="d4_grey.png" data-alt="green" style="width:64px;">
      </button></td>
    <td>
      <button>
        <img id="d6_image" src="d6_grey.png" data-alt="red" style="width:64px">
      </button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`HTMLElement.dataset` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).
- [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: Thank you @David Thomas for your detailed explanation. I learned so many things. My mistake was a little bit stupid. With more research, I could probably have figured that out myself. But the options you told me to optimize my code are awesome. Thank you and keep up your good work. Have a wonderfull day!

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

looks like a simple bug. `document.getElementById('dice')` is referencing an id that doesn't exist on the page. Try setting it to either `d4_image` or `d6_image`, the ids of the two buttons.

eg: `document.getElementById('d4_image')`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the element for 'dice' which is giving you null when accessed.

Suggested change to move JS to end of script and to add 'alt=...' references should the images not be available.

```js
  console.clear();
  function pickDice(dice) {
    var img = document.getElementById('dice');

    console.log(img.src)

    if (img.src.match("d4_grey.png")) {
      img.src = "d4_green.png";
      img.alt = "d4_green.png";
    } else
    if (img.src.match("d4_green.png")) {
      img.src = "d4_grey.png";
      img.alt = "d4_grey.png";
    } else
    if (img.src.match("d6_grey.png")) {
      img.src = "d6_red.png";
      img.alt = "d6_red.png";
    } else
    if (img.src.match("d6_red.png")) {
      img.src = "d6_grey.png";
      img.alt = "d6_grey.png";
    }
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>P&P System</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="style.css?v=<?=time();?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58841549/change-multiple-images-in-buttons -->

<style>
 img { width: 64px; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>P&P System</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button onclick="pickDice('d4_image')">
          <img id="d4_image" src="d4_grey.png" alt="d4_grey.png">
        </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="pickDice('d6_image')">
          <img id="d6_image" src="d6_grey.png" alt="d6_grey.png">
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <img id="dice" src="d4_grey.png" alt="d4_grey.png">

<!-- place JS snippit here -->
</body>
</html>
```